# How to calculate the week number so that a week number does not overlap with two months in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a new variable in which the weeks are assigned but i don't want the week to overlap between 2 months. So suppose in Jan'23 week 5 has 30,31 and the rest from Feb 1,2,3 and so on. Jan 30,31 should be assigned week5 and the dates from Feb as week6

```py
import datetime
import time


def getDateRangeFromWeek(p_year,p_week):
    firstdayofweek = datetime.datetime.strptime('{}-W{}-1'.format(p_year,int(p_week)-1), "%Y-W%W-%w").date()
    lastdayofweek = firstdayofweek + datetime.timedelta(days=7)
    return firstdayofweek, lastdayofweek
```

this function gives me the first day and last day of a week and bases this i define the week

```py
for i in frange('1-53'):
    firstdate, lastdate =  getDateRangeFromWeek('2023',str(i))
    dataset[(dataset['starttime'] >= firstdate) & (dataset['starttime'] <= lastdate), 'week_DP_2023'] = i
```

Comment: What is your expected output? And for 2023-01-01 (Sunday), what is the week number?

Comment: for 2023-01-01 the week number is 1 and for 2023-01-02 the week number will be 2

Comment: So the week for 30/31 January is 6 and not 5? Can you my answer. You can modify the week numbering with `range(1, len(dti))`.

Comment: is it possible to somehow connect so that i can show you my exact problem?

Comment: Try to explain it with your question. Update input data, show expected output. Take the time to read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I get this error when i run pd.cut - TypeError: Cannot cast ufunc less input from dtype('<m8[ns]') to dtype('<m8') with casting rule 'same_kind'

Comment: That's why you have to provide a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of dates to use with `pd.cut`:

```
# create a minimal reproducible example
df = pd.DataFrame({'starttime': pd.date_range('2023-01-20', '2023-02-10')})

# generate all days of a year
dti = pd.date_range('2023-1-1', '2023-12-1')

# keep only monday and first day of month as bins
dti = dti[(dti.weekday == 0) | (dti.day == 1)]

# set week number according requirements
df['week'] = pd.cut(df['starttime'], bins=dti, labels=range(len(dti)-1), right=False)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    starttime week
0  2023-01-20    3
1  2023-01-21    3
2  2023-01-22    3
3  2023-01-23    4
4  2023-01-24    4
5  2023-01-25    4
6  2023-01-26    4
7  2023-01-27    4
8  2023-01-28    4
9  2023-01-29    4
10 2023-01-30    5  # Monday
11 2023-01-31    5  # Thuesday
12 2023-02-01    6  # Wednesday, another month week+1
13 2023-02-02    6  # Thursday
14 2023-02-03    6  # Friday
15 2023-02-04    6  # Saturday
16 2023-02-05    6  # Sunday
17 2023-02-06    7  # A new week begins
18 2023-02-07    7
19 2023-02-08    7
20 2023-02-09    7
21 2023-02-10    7
```